# Don't know how to define my swap function properly

Tags: c, pointers

I can understand pointers to a certain extent but the multiple layers of dereferencing in `swap()` is confusing me. Thus,I'm unable to implement it correctly.

Below is a code on alphabetizing based on insertion sort:

```
void insertionSort(char **array,int rows,int cols)
{
   for(int i=1;i<=rows-1;i++)
   {
      for(int j=i-1;strcmp(array[i],array[j])<0 && j>=0;j--)
      {
         swap(&array[i],&array[j]);
         i--; //when swapped, subscript of key also drops
      }
   }
}

void swap(char **s1,char**s2)
{
   char **temp=s1;
   strcpy(*s1,*s2);
   strcpy(*s2,*temp);
}
```

I know the `swap()` is wrongly implemented. I hopefully would like to know how to step through the thinking process to correctly implement `swap()`(ie how to understand the muliple layers of dereferencing better)

Comment: For insertion sort, there's a sorted subarray on the left and unsorted on the right. The first element can be considered to be sorted since its by itself. So I kind of skipped the first element.

Comment: OK,  Still `for(int i=1;i<rows;i++)` is easier to understand than `for(int i=1;i<=rows-1;i++) `.

Comment: I think it's up to preference. I like to have the `<=` sign so that when reading code, I can see the ending subscript without doing the "minus 1" process in my head. Still it's just preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `strcpy` at all. You simply want to swap two `char *`s, to which you have pointers (`char **`s). As such, the implementation should be the same as any other swap. The temporary should be a `char *`, and you should be swapping the `char *` values, not copying the strings that lie behind them.

```
void swap(char **s1,char **s2)
{
   char *temp = *s1;
   *s1 = *s2;
   *s2 = temp;
}
```

This is exactly the same as e.g. a function for swapping `int`s, except with `int` replaced by `char *`.

Comment: This definitely is easier for me to understand. But for curiosity sake, i want to know what  went wrong with my definition?

Comment: @Leon `char **tmp = s1` makes a new pointer-to-`char *` that points to the same string that `s1` does (it doesn't copy the string contents). The first `strcpy` copies the contents of `*s2` into `*s1`, so both strings have s2's contents. The second `strcpy` copies the contents of `*temp` (which is the same as `*s1`, and therefore contains the original contents of `*s2`) into `*s2`. It would have worked (albeit inefficiently) if you had allocated a new temporary `char *` and done *three* `strcpy`s, but what you wrote is mixing different "depths" of copying, which is why it fails.

Comment: Doesn't `*temp` have the original contents of `*s1`-so what do you mean when you said  and therefore contains the original contents of  `*s2`? If what I say is correct(which is not but I don't understand why), two `strcpy`s should be sufficient right?

Comment: Also, why are they different "depths" of copying s1,s2,temp are pointers to ` char*`. and all I did was dereference them